# Anchor SlidingTabLayout at the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, xml

i'm like new at android. I have a slidingTabLayout, what i want to do is :

1.put the tabs at the bottom of the screen
2.put icon instead of text on tab title.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    />

<com.androidsources.welcomescreen.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    ></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

This is my MainActivity.xml file. SlidingTabStrip.cs & SlidingTabLayout.cs aren't changed

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <com.leigo.eyepetizer.ui.view.slidingtab.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```